# Ubuntu 20.04 weird extra additon to URLs after performing searches

Tags: ubuntu, search-engine, canonical-link, duckduckgo

I started noticing something interesting as I perform internet searches using DuckDuckGo in Firefox on Ubuntu. After I hit Enter, this gets added to the URL:

`&t=canonical&atb=v226-1rf&ia=web`

Is this a concern for my searches being sent to Canonical or being recorded in any way? How can I turn this off?

Comment: The Tweet leads to loads of relevant information, including https://help.duckduckgo.com/duckduckgo-help-pages/privacy/t/

Comment: Thanks, sorry about the quick post.. I literally ran into this right after I posted. I was looking for the complete line and after breaking it up I started getting proper answers...

https://help.duckduckgo.com/duckduckgo-help-pages/privacy/atb/